# Home network WAN appears to break work domain LAN adaptor configuration

Tags: dhcp, lan

When I connect my windows 7 laptop to my home network via WAN (WORKGROUP), then the next day connect the laptop to my work docking station (domain on lan) my  network settings seem to be wrecked.

I have only been able to reestablish connectivity with work domain after

1. rebooting
2. Disable ipv4/ipv6 and LAN network adapter
3. explicitly specify ipaddress, gateway and dns server
4. Re-enable ipv4/ipv6 and LAN network adapter

I can then change settings back to automatic and DHCP will work normally. 
If I use my home docking station, I don't have these problems. 
I haven't explicitly tested shutdown/sleep/hibernate, however, I feel like the problem is more prevalent when I move the machine between networks in sleep mode.

Please let me know if additional information may help diagnose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right.  One, WAN in this case is not applicable.  It's still a LAN.  Two, you're carrying over your IP address from work to home.  To fix it you need to release the DHCP lease and renew it at either location.

From a command prompt, type `ipconfig /release`, hit Enter, then type `ipconfig /renew`.

This should resolve the problem.

Comment: +1 Real common issue.  Especially if both networks are on same subnet.  If that is the case, changing the subnet  at home can help as well.

Comment: WAN was supposed to be wireless, as the issue is only caused by using the wireless adapter. Using the docking station (which has ethernet cable), their is no problem, ethernet cable directly to laptop, no problem, just wireless. I agree  ipconfig /renew (which will do it's own /release if necessary) usually fixes the problem,  but not in this case, nor was waving in the direction of ipconfig DNS (flush/register). Much time (always starting by testing ipconfig, real problem?) trying to fix networking without rebooting. The mentioned process is the minimum I've found to fix my network gremlins.

Comment: Replaced the machine, with new dell, and no more problem. Credit for attendence ;)